# Retrieve the time needed by a user to complete form in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to retrieve the time taken by a user to complete a form when using Symfony form.

My current code is as follows ( I have an entity and its associated Form):

```
$entity = new Entity();
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new EntityType(), $entity);

$begin_time = new \DateTime();

if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
    $end_time = new \DateTime();
    $delta_time = $end_time->diff($begin_time);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

When I send the form, my variable $begin_date and $end_date are equal, thus my interval is null. Is this because the controller is reinitialized when sending the form and as a result, $begin_time is modified again ?

I also tried to create a condition when the form isn't being sent :

```
if(!$form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
     $begin_time = new \DateTime();
}
```

However, I still obtain $begin_time equal to $end_time. So my question is, is it possible to obtain the interval of time needed by user to complete the form and how to do this in Symfony ?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `$begin_time = $entity->getDate();` Could you show us how that date is initialized in the Entity constructor?

Comment: It is an error, in fact it is $begin_time = \DateTime();  I will edit the question.

Comment: then you are setting $begin_time it in submission time. You need to somehow save that timestamp value to the form on request (before the if), and then recover it in submission handling (inside the if).

Comment: "When I send the form, my variable $begin_date and $end_date are equal,", actually, they are not. $end_date is not even set, since when you send the form, the inside of the `if(..)` doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [hidden input](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html) to the EntityType with the "data" parameter set to the current timestamp.

```
//Untested code
$builder->add('begin_date', HiddenType::class, array(
    'data' => time(),
    'mapped' => false
));
```

In the form submission handling, get the current timestamp on the server and substract the amount you received in the hidden input.

```
//Untested code
if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
    $begin_time = $form->getData()['begin_date'];
    $end_time = new \DateTime();
    $delta_time = $end_time->diff($begin_time);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

The important thing is that you need to get the $begin_data value *from the form data*, which contains the value that you set on the original request.

Now $delta_time should give you the time in seconds from the loading on the page and the submission (ignoring network transmission & browser render time).

---

If you want to measure from the time the user starts writing on the form you can bind a function to the "input" event on the form so it sets the hidden input the first time it is triggered.

Comment: I tried your solution and in my EntityType.php I added :
$builder->add('begin_data', 'hidden', array(
                    'data' => new DateTime() ))
But I get the error "Neither the property "begin_data" nor one of the methods "getBeginData()", "beginData()", "isBeginData()", "hasBeginData()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class Entity.

Does this mean that I have to add these methods to my Entity file ?

Comment: @modkin no, you just need to set the ['mapped' property](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html#mapped) to false. Sorry, I forgot to mention it!

Comment: Yes, now this part works, thank you. Do I need to render the hidden field in the form itself ? Now I'm getting this error : "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime could not be converted to string"